# HTTPError 400 while deploying production-ready GitLab on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I'm following the official [Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-production-ready-gitlab-on-gke) for Deploying production-ready GitLab on Google Kubernetes Engine.

The step Create the PostgreSQL instance and database: 1. Create the Cloud SQL database that GitLab will use to store most of its metadata gave me the Error:

```
gcloud beta sql instances create gitlab-db --network default \
    --database-version=POSTGRES_9_6 --cpu 4 --memory 15 --no-assign-ip \
    --storage-auto-increase --zone us-central1-a
```

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.instances.create) HTTPError 400: Invalid request: Project {here_stands_my_correct_Project_ID} has invalid private network 
name https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{here_stands_my_correct_Project_ID}/global/networks/default.
```

Any ideas, thank you?

EDIT: I used the following command and edited manually the gilab-db to Private IP with attached Network (default) in the Console getting a 503 Error at the end of the the tutorial.

```
gcloud beta sql instances create gitlab-db --database-version=POSTGRES_9_6 --cpu 4 --memory 15 --storage-auto-increase --zone us-central1-a
```

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                   READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
gitlab-certmanager-788c6859c6-szqqm                    1/1     Running                 0          28m
gitlab-gitaly-0                                        0/1     Pending                 0          28m
gitlab-gitlab-runner-6cfb858756-l8gxr                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff        6          28m
gitlab-gitlab-shell-6cc87fcd4c-2mqph                   1/1     Running                 0          28m
gitlab-gitlab-shell-6cc87fcd4c-jvp8n                   1/1     Running                 0          27m
gitlab-issuer.1-cx8tm                                  0/1     Completed               0          28m
gitlab-nginx-ingress-controller-5f486c5f7b-md8rj       1/1     Running                 0          28m
gitlab-nginx-ingress-controller-5f486c5f7b-rps6m       1/1     Running                 0          28m
gitlab-nginx-ingress-controller-5f486c5f7b-xc8fv       1/1     Running                 0          28m
gitlab-nginx-ingress-default-backend-7f87d67c8-6xhhz   1/1     Running                 0          28m
gitlab-nginx-ingress-default-backend-7f87d67c8-7w2s2   1/1     Running                 0          28m
gitlab-registry-8dfc8f979-9hdbr                        0/1     Init:0/2                0          28m
gitlab-registry-8dfc8f979-qr5nd                        0/1     Init:0/2                0          27m
gitlab-sidekiq-all-in-1-88f47878-26nh8                 0/1     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   7          28m
gitlab-task-runner-74fc4ccdb9-pm592                    1/1     Running                 0          28m
gitlab-unicorn-5b74ffdff8-4kkj4                        0/2     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   7          28m
gitlab-unicorn-5b74ffdff8-nz662                        0/2     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   7          27m
kube-state-metrics-57b88466db-h7xkj                    1/1     Running                 0          27m
node-exporter-q4bpv                                    1/1     Running                 0          27m
node-exporter-x8mtj                                    1/1     Running                 0          27m
node-exporter-xrdlv                                    1/1     Running                 0          27m
prometheus-k8s-5cf4c4cf6c-hsntr                        2/2     Running                 1          27m
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the command that generated the error. Error 400 usually means that one of the parameters is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this is because it's still in `beta` and not all features and/or options are working correctly.

I can advice that you check if you have just one network available.

You can do that by using `gcloud compute networks list`.

```
$ gcloud compute networks list
NAME     SUBNET_MODE  BGP_ROUTING_MODE  IPV4_RANGE  GATEWAY_IPV4
default  AUTO         REGIONAL
```

If you see only `default` network then there is no need to worry about providing the `--network` flag at all.

Also form what it looks like the instance will need to use an IP either Public or Private so you can leave out the flag `--no-assign-ip`.

Working command might look like this:

```
gcloud beta sql instances create gitlab-db --database-version=POSTGRES_9_6 --cpu 4 --memory 15 --storage-auto-increase --zone us-central1-a
```

You can read the docs about the flags and usage on [gcloud beta sql instances create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/sql/instances/create)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have only the default network and used the command, that you provided and therefore I cut the parameter --no-assign-ip. Then I switch manually in the Console for my gitlab-db from "public IP" to "private ip: "default" as linked network". All the following commands in the tutorial seem to work immediately, beside the fact I can only provide 8 vCpu in total (Trial Account) and the command "./helm update" is outdated. But now i try to reach my GitLab getting a 503 Error from nginx. I checked my pods and edited my inital Questions.

Comment: You would be better of to submit a new question for those errors with gitlab pods. It also would be helpful if you check the event's/logs for those pods, what the errors is about. You could do that by using `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`